# Brakeman Scan Controller and View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I have a controller `sample_controller.rb` and related views under `app/views/sample`.

Now I want to scan for security issues using brakeman.
My first approach is to do scanning seperately like below:

```
brakeman --only-files app/controller/sample_controller.rb
brakeman --only-files app/views/sample
```

And the second approach is to scan both controller and view in the same 
command like below:

```
brakeman --only-files app/controller/sample_controller.rb , app/views/sample
```

The problem is that I get different results in both approaches.

Which is the correct approach. Please let me know.

Comment: How do the results differ?

Comment: Have you tried without the embedded blanks?  `brakeman --only-files app/controller/sample_controller.rb,app/views/sample`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass in multiple files is to separate them with a comma, as stated in the help documentation:

```
--only-files file1,path2,etc Process only these files/directories. Directories are application relative and must end in "/"
```

However, you are **extremely discouraged** from using this approach. Brakeman works best when it is able to access the entire application, not just individual files. It can't even determine the Rails version in use if you just provide a controller and a view.

Instead, just run

```
brakeman
```

in the directory of your application.

Alternatively you can provide a directory like `brakeman path/to/my/thing` or `brakeman --path path/to/my/thing`.